# Choosing which base class to override method of

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, observer-pattern

Given the following:

```
class Observer
{
    public:
        virtual void Observe(Parameter p) = 0;
};

template<size_t Tag>
class TaggedObserver : public Observer { };

class Thing : public TaggedObserver<0>, TaggedObserver<1>
{
    public:
        virtual void Observe(Parameter p) override;
};
```

`Thing::Observe` overrides both `TaggedObserver<0>::Observe` and `TaggedObserver<1>::Observe`.
Is there a way to provide a different override for each base class?
Rationale: I want the class to be able to observe two notification sources of the same type with different actions for each source without having to resort to pass the source in the parameter and then checking it in an `if`/`switch`.

Comment: `TaggedObserver<0>` and `TaggedObserver<1>` are the same class. Why not make two child classes?

Comment: @JimV: They are not. The point of them being templated is to differentiate the base classes.

Comment: @JimV: `TaggedObserver<0>` and `TaggedObserver<1>` may be based on the same *template* class, but they are different *instantiated* classes. Just like `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<char>` are different classes, for instance.  Template parameter values are part of the class type and produce different RTTI results.

Comment: I had an idea, but so far it only resulted in a new question: [case of template member function specialization that works on msvc, not others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276005/case-of-template-member-function-specialization-that-works-on-msvc-not-others).

Comment: The description of what you want is fairly vague. Voted to close as **lacking example** (of that).

Comment: P.S. FWIW an alternative solution was posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38280119/5538420) as an answer to my related question. Like @skypjack's answer below, it uses CRTP to "remap" the base `Observe` to a templetized `Thing::Observe<N>`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to provide different overrides, you need to define different derived classes, eg:

```
class Observer
{
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p) = 0;
};

template<size_t Tag>
class TaggedObserver : public Observer
{
};

class TaggedObserverZero : public TaggedObserver<0>
{
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p)
    {
        // do something ...
    }
};

class TaggedObserverOne : public TaggedObserver<1>
{
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p)
    {
        // do something else ...
    }
};
```

However, if you want `Thing::Observe()` to receive the `Parameter` first and dispatch it to the appropriate base class, you can't avoid using an `if` statement (or equivalent) in `Thing`, since it inherits multiple copies of `TaggedObserver::Observe()` and needs to decide which one to call:

```
class Thing : public Observer, TaggedObserverZero, TaggedObserverOne
{
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p)
    {
        if (some condition)
            TaggedObserverZero::Observe(p);
        else if (some other condition)
            TaggedObserverOne::Observe(p);
    }
};
```

Or, you call just them both unconditionally and let them figure out what to do:

```
class TaggedObserverZero : public TaggedObserver<0>
{
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p)
    {
        if (some condition)
            // do something ...
    }
};

class TaggedObserverOne : public TaggedObserver<1>
{
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p)
    {
        if (some other condition)
            // do something else ...
    }
};

class Thing : public Observer, TaggedObserverZero, TaggedObserverOne
{
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p)
    {
        TaggedObserverZero::Observe(p);
        TaggedObserverOne::Observe(p);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement them in `TaggedObserver` (provide explicit specialization if needed), as an example:

```
class Observer {
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p) = 0;
};

template<size_t Tag>
class TaggedObserver : public Observer {
public:
    void Observe(Parameter p) override { }
};

template<std::size_t... I>
class Thing : public TaggedObserver<I>... {
public:
    Thing(): TaggedObserver<I>{}... {}

    template<std::size_t N>
    void Observe(Parameter p) {
        TaggedObserver<N>::Observe(p);
    }
};
```

Then, you can specialize `Thing` as `Thing<0, 1>` and invoke the right function using `thing.Observe<1>(p)`.

**EDIT**

The purpose of this edit is to show a new example code, that is more or less the one above even if slightly modified.
I hope this can help the OP. The basic idea is to combine CRTP idiom, virtual methods and inheritance.

```
class Observer {
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p) = 0;
};

template<template T, size_t Tag>
class TaggedObserver : public Observer {
public:
    void Observe(Parameter p) override {
        T *t = static_cast<T*>(this);
        // Now use whatever you want from T, that is Thing in this example
    }
};

template<std::size_t... I>
class Thing : public TaggedObserver<Thing<I...>, I>... {
     template<std::size_t J>
     friend class TaggedObserver<Thing<I...>, J>;

public:
    Thing(): TaggedObserver<Thing<I...>, I>{}... {}

    template<std::size_t N>
    void Observe(Parameter p) {
        TaggedObserver<Thing<I...>, N>::Observe(p);
    }
};
```

Note that the `friend` declaration allows `TaggedObserver`s to access private members of `Thing`.

This way, implementations of `Observe` in `TaggedObserver`s can access public, protected and private members from `Thing`, as requested in the comments.

Finally you can specialize `TaggedObserver` if needed, so as to provide different implementations for `Observe`.
As an example:

```
template<template T, size_t Tag>
class TaggedObserver;

template<template T>
class TaggedObserver<T, 0>: public Observer {
public:
    void Observe(Parameter p) override {
        T *t = static_cast<T*>(this);
        // Now use whatever you want from T, that is Thing in this example
        // Put here the code of the specialization for Tag 0
    }
};

template<template T>
class TaggedObserver<T, 1>: public Observer {
public:
    void Observe(Parameter p) override {
        T *t = static_cast<T*>(this);
        // Now use whatever you want from T, that is Thing in this example
        // Put here the code of the specialization for Tag 1
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to move `template<std::size_t N> void Observe(Parameter p)` somewhere higher up, as to not need to duplicate it in every `Thing`-like class? That's what I was trying to do at [case of template member function specialization that works on msvc, not others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276005/case-of-template-member-function-specialization-that-works-on-msvc-not-others) but didn't find the right spell.

Comment: My intention was not to be able to call a different `TaggedObserver::Observe` method, that is already possible using `thing->TaggedObserver<N>::Observe`. My intention was that `Thing` would have a different override for each `TaggedObserver::Observe`

Comment: @Dani Why cannot you define them in `TaggedObserver`? This way, `Thing` will inherit those specializations. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @skypjack: Because they need some of the `Thing` members

Comment: @Dani Answer updated. Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: @skypjack: That does not solve it completely: to distinguish which `TaggedObserver` it is I need to do an `if`/`switch` over `Tag`. What I want is different function bodies for each `TaggedObserver` coexisting in `Thing`. That is architecturally possible since the `Thing vtable for TaggedObserver<0>` is different from `Thing vtable for TaggedObserver<1>`. What I want is a way to have a different function for each `vtable`

Comment: @Dani This way you can have it using specialization. Let me integrate the answer with this information.