# case of template member function specialization that compiles on msvc, not others

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

*[ EDIT ]* I changed the title from `works` to `compiles` since it turns out that it doesn't truly work after all (thanks @bogdan for the comments). I added code at the end of the post showing why and how.

The second part of the question still stands - is there a way to "*fix*" it? The crux of the matter is having a virtual function `Observe` in a base `template<int N> class X` be rerouted to a templated function `Observe<N>` in classes derived from `X<N>`, without requiring any supporting code in `X`.

For an example of how it can be done by requiring `X` to cooperate see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275593/5538420) to the other question (which basically requires that `Observe<N>` be declared into the most derived class).

---

While looking at this other question [Choosing which base class to override method of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271718/choosing-which-base-class-to-override-method-of) I found out that the following snippet compiles cleanly on `vc++ 2015` (with `/W4 /Za`) and returns the expected output, yet fails to compile on  `gcc-5.1` and `clang 3.7` (tried at [ideone.com](https://ideone.com)).

I am aware that specialization of template functions has many pitfalls, but I am still curious which letter of the C++ standard applies in this case, and - in the likely case that the code is not fully compliant - whether there is an easy way to "fix" it.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef int Parameter;

class Observer
{
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p) = 0;
};

class TaggedDispatch
{
public:
    template<size_t Tag> void TObserve(Parameter p);
};

template<size_t Tag>
class TaggedObserver : virtual public TaggedDispatch, public Observer 
{ 
public:
    virtual void Observe(Parameter p) override
    {   TObserve<Tag>(p); }
};

class Thing : public TaggedObserver<0>, TaggedObserver<11>
{   };

template<> void Thing::TObserve<0>(Parameter p)
{   cout << "Parent #  0, Parameter " << p << endl; }

template<> void Thing::TObserve<11>(Parameter p)
{   cout << "Parent # 11, Parameter " << p << endl; }

int main(int, char **)
{
    Thing test;
    test.TObserve<0>(101);
    test.TObserve<11>(999);

    return 0;
}
```

Output when compiled with `vc++ 2015`.

```
Parent #  0, Parameter 101
Parent # 11, Parameter 999
```

Compile errors from`gcc-5.1`

```
prog.cpp:29:17: error: template-id 'TObserve<0>' for 'void Thing::TObserve(Parameter)' does not match any template declaration
 template<> void Thing::TObserve<0>(Parameter p)
                 ^
prog.cpp:32:17: error: template-id 'TObserve<11>' for 'void Thing::TObserve(Parameter)' does not match any template declaration
 template<> void Thing::TObserve<11>(Parameter p)
```

Compile errors from `clang 3.7`.

```
prog.cpp:22:36: warning: 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        virtual void Observe(Parameter p) override
                                          ^
prog.cpp:29:24: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'TObserve'
template<> void Thing::TObserve<0>(Parameter p)
                       ^
prog.cpp:32:1: error: extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'TObserve'
template<> void Thing::TObserve<11>(Parameter p)
^~~~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:32:24: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
template<> void Thing::TObserve<11>(Parameter p)
                       ^
prog.cpp:32:32: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
template<> void Thing::TObserve<11>(Parameter p)
                               ^
                               ;
prog.cpp:32:32: error: expected unqualified-id
1 warning and 5 errors generated.
```

---

*[ EDIT ]* It doesn't truly work in `vc++ 2015` after all. What appears to happen is that the compiler allows the `void Thing::TObserve<0>` definition, but internally maps it to `void TaggedDispatch::TObserve<0>`. This becomes obvious if adding another derived class e.g.

```
class Other : public TaggedObserver<0>
{    };

template<> void Other::TObserve<0>(Parameter p)
{    cout << "Parent # 00, Parameter " << p << endl; }
```

Then the `vc++ 2015` compile fails with the error message:

```
error C2766: explicit specialization; 'void TaggedDispatch::TObserve<0>(Parameter)' has already been defined
```

Comment: OK, I'll clean up the comments and move the information into an answer here. The two questions complement each other, so the answers could do the same.

Comment: Done. The bug in MSVC should be reported. Should I do that, or do you want to report it yourself?

Comment: @bogdan I agree that's worth reporting. If you don't mind go ahead and do it. Thanks.

Comment: MSVC bug [reported on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2931941/vc-14-update-3-incorrectly-accepts-a-member-template-explicit-specialization-declaration-that-refers-to-a-derived-class).

Comment: @bogdan. Thanks. Repro'd and upvoted on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2931941/vc-14-update-3-incorrectly-accepts-a-member-template-explicit-specialization-declaration-that-refers-to-a-derived-class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC is wrong to accept the code; Clang and GCC (and EDG) are right to reject it.

This case is similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38215737/4326278), but it involves a different syntactic construct (and different code paths in the compilers, yielding different Standard conformance results, with only EDG being consistent).

In `template<> void Thing::TObserve<0>(Parameter p)`, `Thing::TObserve<0>` is a *declarator-id*, with `Thing::` being a *nested-name-specifier*. [8.3p1] says:

> [...] When the *declarator-id* is qualified, the declaration shall refer
>   to a previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the
>   qualifier refers (or, in the case of a namespace, of an element of the
>   inline namespace set of that namespace (7.3.1)) or to a specialization
>   thereof; the member shall not merely have been introduced by a
>   *using-declaration* in the scope of the class or namespace nominated by
>   the *nested-name-specifier* of the *declarator-id*. [...]

So, you have to use `template<> void TaggedDispatch::TObserve<0>`. As noted in the question, using `Thing::` could create the false impression that you can provide different explicit specializations of `TObserve` for different derived classes, which is not the case. There's only one `TObserve` member function template, the one declared in `TaggedDispatch`, and all such explicit specializations (and implicit or explicit instantiations, and partial specializations) are "attached" to that declaration.

---

One solution to make things work the way you expect is to declare an `Observe` member function template in each derived `Thing`-like class,  possibly providing explicit specializations for relevant `Tag`s if necessary, and let specializations of the template be automatically wired up to the corresponding `Observer` interface instance using CRTP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using Parameter = int;

struct Observer 
{
   virtual void Observe(Parameter p) = 0;
};

template<std::size_t Tag> struct TaggedObserver : Observer { };

template<class Derived, std::size_t Tag> struct CrtpObserver : TaggedObserver<Tag>
{
   void Observe(Parameter p) override
   {
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->template Observe<Tag>(p);
   }
};

struct Thing : CrtpObserver<Thing, 0>, CrtpObserver<Thing, 1>
{
   template<std::size_t N> void Observe(Parameter p);
};

template<> void Thing::Observe<0>(Parameter p)
{
   std::cout << "Interface #0, Parameter " << p << '\n';
}

template<> void Thing::Observe<1>(Parameter p)
{
   std::cout << "Interface #1, Parameter " << p << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   Thing test;
   TaggedObserver<0>* p0 = &test;
   TaggedObserver<1>* p1 = &test;
   p0->Observe(7);
   p1->Observe(3);
}
```

This places the implementations of the `Observer` interface in `Thing` where they belong, while requiring minimal plumbing in each derived class - not much more than what you would have to do anyway if you could separately override each `Observer::Observe` directly.